# /proc/interrupts not showing all irqs

Tags: linux, redhat, interrupt, procfs, irq

I am working on a program that fetches all irqs in /proc/irq and does some parsing. I've realized however that there are a bunch of irq numbers in /proc/irq that are not listed in /proc/interrupts. For example, on my system, /proc/irq includes directories for irqs 1, 2, 3, however these irqs do not show up in /proc/interrupts. What is the reason for this?